# Threadsafe OpenSSL in a single-threaded use?

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-8, openssl, winsock2

I've completely re-written this question because hopefully I can get some more useful answers this way.

I've got a multithreaded client/server application with a single `winsock2` socket that it uses to 'phone  home' for client-unique information. All of the socket communication is encrypted with OpenSSL before it is transmitted using `SSL_write` and then decrypted with `SSL_read`. We are using blocking sockets, and the berkely-style C calls, inside of a Socket wrapper class to make it object-oriented. There is only 1 instance of this Socket class instantiated in a single thread, and all of the calls to it are done serially within that single thread. The server, who the client is 'phoning home' to, runs on a Server 2008 R2 box. On all versions of windows from 2000 up through 7, the client functions perfectly: it handshakes, gets the information it needs, and closes the connection cleanly.

In Windows 8, the client fails the 'phone home' without explanation and leaves the server in a state of trying to continually read more information from the socket.

One thing that was suggested to me by a coworker was to make sure my OpenSSL was setup to be threadsafe.

Due to several reasons, I believe this is unnecessary, but I need a more informed answer.
**Reason 1:** all of the socket I/O occurs in a single thread.
**Reason 2:** all of the socket calls occur in serial order.
**Reason 3:** it works on all previous versions of Windows prior to 8.

**Would it be important to set OpenSSL to be threadsafe?**

Comment: Are you using AcceptEx or other IOCP related stuff?

Comment: Not using either. Currently using only the __stdcall bind,listen, accept,shutdown,closesocket stuff inside of a custom Socket class. Before the OpenGL Document starts the handshaking thread, the constructor for the 'handshaking' class queues up several functions to be executed, and then when the thread starts it starts dequeue'ing them and then executing each item, and depending on their returned values it either continues to the next item or returns false. Are there specific things I should check regarding IOCP? I will admit ignorance of its' existence until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to set up the OpenSSL callbacks to make it thread safe so why not just do it and see if the problem goes away.

Whilst you've reasoned that there's no need to do so the fact that there's a potential problem shouldn't blind you to a potentially easy fix to the issue even if "there's no way it should be that"...

Here's the code that I use for this,

```
struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value 
{ 
   CRYPTO_dynlock_value()
   {
      ::InitializeCriticalSection(&crit);
   }

   ~CRYPTO_dynlock_value()
   {
      ::DeleteCriticalSection(&crit);
   }

    CRITICAL_SECTION crit;
}; 

static CRITICAL_SECTION *InitStaticCrit()
{
   CRITICAL_SECTION *pCrit = new CRITICAL_SECTION();

   ::InitializeCriticalSection(pCrit);

   return pCrit;
}

static CRITICAL_SECTION *s_pCriticalSection = InitStaticCrit();

static CRITICAL_SECTION *s_pLocks = 0;

static struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *dyn_create_function(
   const char *file,
   int line) 
{
   (void)file;
   (void)line;

   CRYPTO_dynlock_value *pValue = new CRYPTO_dynlock_value();

   return pValue;
}

static void dyn_lock_function(
   int mode,
   struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *pLock,
   const char *file,
   int line) 
{
   (void)file;
   (void)line;

    if (mode & CRYPTO_LOCK)
    {
       ::EnterCriticalSection(&pLock->crit);
    }
    else
    {
       ::LeaveCriticalSection(&pLock->crit);
    } 
} 

static void dyn_destroy_function(
   struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *pLock,
   const char *file,
   int line) 
{
   (void)file;
   (void)line;

   delete pLock;
}

static bool ThreadingSetup(
   const DWORD spinCount)
{
   ::EnterCriticalSection(&s_criticalSection);

   bool ok = false;

   if (!s_pLocks)
   {
      s_pLocks = (CRITICAL_SECTION *)malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() * sizeof(CRITICAL_SECTION));

      for (int i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++)
      {
         if (spinCount != 0)
         {
#if(_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0403)
            (void)::InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&s_pLocks[i], spinCount);
#else
#pragma warning(suppress: 6011)  // Dereferencing null pointer. No, we're not.
            ::InitializeCriticalSection(&s_pLocks[i]);

            OutputDebugString(_T("CUsesOpenSSL::ThreadingSetup() - spin count specified but _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0403, spin count not used\n"));
#endif
         }
         else
         {
#pragma warning(suppress: 6011)  // Dereferencing null pointer. No, we're not.
            ::InitializeCriticalSection(&s_pLocks[i]);
         }
      }

      CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(LockingCallback);

      //CRYPTO_set_id_callback(id_function); 

      // dynamic locks callbacks

      CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback(dyn_create_function); 
      CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback(dyn_lock_function); 
      CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback(dyn_destroy_function); 

      ok = true;
   }

   ::LeaveCriticalSection(&s_criticalSection);

   return ok;
}

static void ThreadingCleanup()
{
   if (s_pLocks)
   {
      CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(0);

      CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback(0);
      CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback(0);
      CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback(0);

      for (int i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++)
      {
         ::DeleteCriticalSection(&s_pLocks[i]);
      }

      free(s_pLocks);

      s_pLocks = 0;
   }
}

static void LockingCallback(
   int mode,
   int type,
   const char * /*file*/,
   int /*line*/)
{
   if (mode & CRYPTO_LOCK)
   {
      ::EnterCriticalSection(&s_pLocks[type]);
   }
   else
   {
      ::LeaveCriticalSection(&s_pLocks[type]);
   }
}
```

Comment: In an effort to follow your advice, I began to try and set them up, but ran into a road block. For whatever reason, I could not get VS2010 to recognize GetCurrentThreadId() function despite having <Windows.h> included. Any suggestions how to solve that?

Comment: Why do you need GetCurrentThreadId()? I expect you have something confused in your header includes...

Comment: As per the instructions included in "Network Security with OpenSSL", the book I'm using, I need to be able to get the current thread ID for use within the callback functions. WIN32 implies that i would need the GetCurrentThreadId() function and then define it as and define it as THREAD_ID.

Comment: Ah, I see that on page 76, I've added the code I use to my answer, don't use mutex as it's not needed and slower than a critical section. I use the default thread id function; from man page for crypto_set_id_callback "If the application does not register such a callback using CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback(), then a default implementation is used - on Windows and BeOS this uses the system's default thread identifying APIs, and on all other platforms it uses the address of errno. The latter is satisfactory for thread-safety if and only if the platform has a thread-local error number facility."

Comment: So, sorry for the thickheadedness, but I'm looking at page 78 in NSwOSSL and I'm still unclear on how to use these code samples. Should I be actually writing this code into my Socket implementation, or as a part of ssh? Are these functions already defined, and I just have to call the correct CRYPTO_set_dynlock function?

Comment: You're writing callbacks that the OpenSSL code will call when it needs to do locking. You tell it to call the functions by calling the CRYPTO_set_ functions and pass them the function (pointer) to call. See my extended example in my reply. I have a class which sets things up for OpenSSL using RAII and which calls ThreadingSetup() in the ctor and ThreadingCleanup() in the dtor. You then create an instance of this class in main() and that's it all done.

Comment: What is the structure of CRYPTO_dynlock_value? don't see what crit is supposed to be

Comment: You've got me on a good path, thanks! Where is LockingCallback defined? Also throughout ThreadingSetup, you refer to s_pLocks[] but I don't see it defined anywhere, and on the first line of ThreadingSetup my compiler (VS2010 Ultimate) it's complaining that class CCriticalSection doesn't have a member Owner, after i included afxmt.h (according to MSDN library). Ideas? I've already got an SSLSettings class which i'm adding these functions to, and will call them in the ctor/dtor.

Comment: I used: `#if defined(WIN32)` `#define MUTEX_TYPE LPCRITICAL_SECTION` and then i have a member: `static MUTEX_TYPE *s_pLocks = NULL` in the class definition header. i also defined:`struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value { MUTEX_TYPE crit}` i'm still having problems with the dyn_lock_function from above, each time there is a pLock->crit.Enter() and .Leave() , saying `Intellisense: class "CRYPTO_dynlock_value" has no member "crit"` ... If you can explain what kind of bonehead i'm being i'd appreciate it! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I've adjusted the code so that it's more complete (rather than just a rough idea) and also so that it doesn't use my own critical section wrapper class. Hasn't seen a compiler, but should work...

Comment: It took a bit of fiddling for me to sort out that I had to note the static function headers in the .h and then code them in my .cpp, and the structs had to be defined outside of the class, but everything is building now. We'll see if this actually fixes all my problems, or just causes new ones. I'd +1 but my rep is too low. Thanks a bunch!